# Scroll to the bottom when loading a list with Blazor Virtualize component

Tags: javascript, c#, scroll, blazor

When loading a Blazor page, I try to go to the end of a `Virtualize` list to display the last information (messages like a chat application).

So I have the following Blazor code:

```
<div id="messages-container" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:500px">
    <Virtualize Context="message" ItemsProvider="@GetMessages">
        <p>@message.Content</p>
    </Virtualize>
</div>

<script>
    function scrollToBottom() {
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages-container");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
    }
</script>

<button onclick="scrollToBottom();">Manual scroll</button>
```

How can I raise the JS `scrollToBottom()` function after the `Virtualize` has rendered the initial DOM of the first page of messages?

If I execute the `scrollToBottom()` JS function in the `OnAfterRenderAsync()` method of the page, the scroll does not work as expected, because:

- The `ItemsProvider` is not called before the `OnAfterRenderAsync()` method. So no data is retrieved.
- Because no data is retrieved, no DOM is rendered and the `messages-container` is empty and have a `scrollHeight` value defined to `500`.

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scrollToBottom");
}
```

However, after the first page is rendered by the `Virtualize` component, if I click the `Manual scroll` button, the `Virtualize` component is scrolled to the last page of the data (the `scrollHeight` value is defined in this case to `9845` for example).

How can I call the `scrollToBottom()` JS function after the first page of the `Virtualize` component has been rendered ?
Or there is an other way to go to the bottom of a `Virtualize` component (last page) ?